# Querying XPath for nodes that DON'T contain an element which satisfy a condition

Tags: xml, xpath

Can XPath find and return as results nodes that don't contain an element which satisfy a condition?
For example:
If I have this:

```
<ShoppingCenter>
<bookstore>
  <book>
    <year>2005</year>
   <comments> Boring! </comments>
  </book>
</bookstore> 

<bookstore>
  <book>
    <year>2005</year>
  </book>
</bookstore> 

<bookstore>
  <book>
    <year>2005</year>
   <comments> Interesting! </comments>
  </book>
</bookstore> 

</ShoppingCenter>
```

I'd like to get as a result only bookstores which don't have books with comments.
In this case: The second store.

Is it possible? And if so - how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can check for the absence of a node by using `not()`:

```
//bookstore[not(book/comments)]
```

Demo (using [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html)):

```
$ xmllint input.xml --xpath "//bookstore[not(book/comments)]"
<bookstore>
  <book>
    <year>2005</year>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```